# How to unit test an ember controller

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-testing

I have a single action defined in an ember controller that calls 2 separate functions that are part of the controller. I'd like to mock out those functions in a unit test in order to confirm if the action method called the correct function.

My controller looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    functionA() {
        return;
    },
    functionB() {
        return;
    },
    actions: {
        actionMethod(param) {
            if(param) {
                return this.functionA();
            }
            else {
                return this.functionB();
            }
         }
    }
});
```

In practice, the controller works, however in the unit test, functionA and functionB are both undefined. I tried to log `this` to the console, but can't find where functionA and functionB are, so I'm unable to properly mock them. I expected them to be in the top level of the object next to actions, but instead I only found `_actions` with `actionMethod` properly defined.

My unit test looks like below

```
const functionA = function() { return; }
const functionB = function() { return; }
test('it can do something', function(assert) {
    let controller = this.subject();
    // I don't want the real functions to run 
    controller.set('functionA', functionA);
    controller.set('functionB', functionB);
    controller.send('actionMethod', '');
    // raises TypeError: this.functionA is not a function

    // this doesn't work etiher
    // controller.functionB = functionB;
    // controller.functionA = functionA;
    // controller.actions.actionMethod();
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can replace those functions in the testing environment? Or perhaps, is there a better way to test this functionality or set up my controller?

- edit
  typo: this.subject to this.subject()

Comment: Side Note:1.To create controller object you need to call `this.subject()` . 2. `controller.send` method will not return any value to caller

Comment: Whoops typo - I called `this.subject()`. As for `controller.send`, I tried that method as shown above as well as calling `controller.actions.actionMethod()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the functions of the controller in the **unit** test, you can pass parameter to the `this.subject()` function:

```
 let controller = this.subject({
     functionA(){
         //this function overriddes functionA
     },
     functionB(){
         //this function overriddes functionB
     },
 });
```

Look at [the sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e52e93bf3430be112f8eaf5ab7a7fd2c?openFiles=tests.unit.controllers.application-test.js%2C).

This method is especially useful for replacing the injected `service` of the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce corresponding property you are dealing with, let us say `name` property,
So your controllers would be looking like this,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  name:'',
  functionA() {
        this.set('name','A');
    },
    functionB() {
        this.set('name','B');
    },
    actions: {
        actionMethod(param) {
            if(param) {
                return this.functionA();
            }
            else {
                return this.functionB();
            }
         }
    }
});
```

And you can test for the `name` property value after calling `actionMethod`.

```
test(" testing functionA has been called or not", function(assert){
  let controller = this.subject();
  controller.send('actionMethod',true);
  //If you would like to call functionA just say  controller.functionA()
  assert.strictEqual(controller.get('name'),'A',' name property has A if actionMethod arguments true');
  controller.send('actionMethod',false);
  assert.strictEqual(controller.get('name'),'B',' name property has B actionMethod arguments false');
});
```

Comment: I am just trying to answer your question to learn myself, to be frank, I haven't written any testing in my project

Comment: If you would like define properties dynamically while creating object then you need to pass it as argument to `subject` method like we do when we create object using `create()` .  `this.subject({functionA:function(){this.set('name','AA'); return ;}});`